# Android Percent Layout shifts contents to the left on full screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I am designing an app and I came into a bit of a problem.

As you can see in the designer all elements are where they should be (namely clocks, top right target button, and main scale), while in emulator they are shifted left (especially noticeable with the clocks and button).

It seems to fix itself if I don't hide the software buttons, but it appears again if I show the software buttons AND the toolbar (could be screen ratio related?)

I am using `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout` from `'com.android.support:percent:25.3.1'`

Did anyone ever encountered a similar problem?

[image: Shifted content]

UPDATE: Here's the layout itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.tekorius.stalker.MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:keepScreenOn="true">

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Geiger
    android:id="@+id/geiger"
    app:layout_widthPercent="52.604166667%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="93.5185185%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="45%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="4%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Tube
    android:id="@+id/tube"
    app:layout_widthPercent="39.895833333%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="31.018518519%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="60%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="52%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.ArmorBar
    android:id="@+id/armorbar"
    app:layout_widthPercent="46.302083333%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="10.185185185%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="3%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3.5%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.StaminaBar
    android:id="@+id/staminabar"
    app:layout_widthPercent="46.302083333%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="11.666666667%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="13%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3.5%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Radbar
    android:id="@+id/radbar"
    app:layout_widthPercent="39.010416667%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="20.740740741%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="21.25%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3.5%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Healthbar
    android:id="@+id/healthbar"
    app:layout_widthPercent="39.010416667%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="20.740740741%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="42.25%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="3.5%" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/qrbutton"
    android:background="@drawable/qr_button"
    app:layout_widthPercent="8.072916667%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="14.351851852%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="89.5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="2%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Clock
    android:id="@+id/clock"
    app:layout_widthPercent="10.15625%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7.87037037%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="88.75%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="84.4%" />

<com.tekorius.stalker.view.Clock
    android:id="@+id/battery"
    app:layout_widthPercent="10.15625%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7.87037037%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="43.5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="84.4%" />

<Button
    app:layout_widthPercent="10.15625%"
    app:layout_heightPercent="7.87037037%"
    app:layout_marginLeftPercent="23.5%"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="84.4%"
    android:text="Start game service"
    android:onClick="startGameService" />

</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your layout file so we can see what's under the hood.

Comment: Well, because your emulator has another screen dimension, than preview screen in Android Studio.

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider here's the layout, nothing fancy, both position and size are the percent based. Updating the original post

Comment: @azizbekian I understand that, that's why I'm using percent relative layout. My design is full HD and I want the elements to always stay in same position and be same size even if it means squishing it.

I've successfully implemented that last year and it's the first time I'm seeing this problem

Comment: Is the aspect ratio the same on the emulator and preview screen?

Comment: @TheHungryAndroider they are a bit different due to preview having the software buttons, but this shouldn't change the overall percentage behavior (mathematically speaking).

I've ran through different device sizes, resolutions and aspect ratios in the preview and they are all working correctly.

Even in portrait mode everything is in place even though a bit squished: http://imgur.com/a/ItCfe

While I agree this could be aspect ratio related, mathematically thinking it shouldn't be. Unless there's something wrong with the onMeasure triggering.

Comment: I'm stumped! Everything looks fine... :/